# Remove one of each duplicated values from table, which is the correct DELETE statement?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete one of each duplicated rows (same product_id). Which is the correct query ? 
What I've reached so far:

```
DELETE FROM `sm_m2epro_listing_product_BACK` WHERE product_id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.product_id
  FROM sm_m2epro_listing_product_BACK a
  WHERE listing_id =8
  GROUP BY a.product_id
  HAVING COUNT( a.product_id ) > 1) qq);
```

But the query returns "NO rows affected" even if the duplicated rows are present.

Comment: Put a sample of your data in a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com), please?

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: As intended, this will actually delete all product_ids with count > 1. One approach is to delete on the `Max()` of the primary key/unique identifier that have product_id counts > 1.

Comment: Which one do you want to delete?

Comment: it doesn't matter which, the first duplicated could be ok

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3c28/1), after getting those repeated rows you need to keep one, I've used a column 'name' *(you could use the primary key if you have one)* to discriminate a row, you should use a column that is not repeated in two rows with same product_id value:

```
DELETE FROM `sm_m2epro_listing_product_BACK` 
  WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM (SELECT a.product_id
  FROM sm_m2epro_listing_product_BACK a
  WHERE listing_id =8
  GROUP BY a.product_id
  HAVING COUNT( a.product_id ) > 1) qq)
and name not in (select min(name) from (SELECT a.name
  FROM sm_m2epro_listing_product_BACK a
  WHERE listing_id =8
  GROUP BY a.product_id
  HAVING COUNT( a.product_id ) > 1) qq);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM `sm_m2epro_listing_product_BACK` 
WHERE listing_id = 8 
and
id not in (select id
           from (select min(id) as id 
                 from `sm_m2epro_listing_product_BACK` 
                 where listing_id = 8 group by id) t)
```

The command above finds the minimum `id` of each group and removes records not having the `id` in the return set. The command assumes you have `id` as primary key.

Comment: This answer is untested, if it has any short-commings, I am welcomming any comments.